# (node:19820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, api, express

I'm trying to create an API using express to upload images to firebase storage.
For some reason when I use this endpoint it throws "(node:19820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined" and it doesn't respond.

```
router.post('/postImage', async (req, res) => {
    try {       
        storage.ref("images/" + uuid()).put({data: "hello"})
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(200)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("ERROR")
        })
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("LOL")
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that causes the error? You're catching everything, there shouldn't be an unhandled promise unless there's an issue within the library you use.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the errors, to pin point where error has occurred.

```
router.post('/postImage', async (req, res) => {
    try {
   const storageRef = storage.ref("images/" + uuid());       
   storageRef.put({ data : "hello" })
        .then(() => {
           res.status(200)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("ERROR: " err);
        });
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("error: "error);
    }
})
```